# SmartTV: sf-ui-list customize items height

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

in one of my scene I have

```
<div id='MenuList'></div>
```

then I add list to it like this:

```
$('#MainListTitles').sfList({
    data : [ 'AAA', 'BBBB', 'CCC']
});
```

How can I customize colors and height of each list item ?? I tried in css like this:

#MenuList.sf-ui-list {height: 333px; text-align: right; background-color:#ffffff} - works

#MenuList.sf-ui-list-item {background-color:#000000} - not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, "#MenuList.sf-ui-list-item" would never work, because you don't have the same element with id "MenuList" and class "sf-ui-list-item". This is basic css. Correct usage would be "#MenuList .sf-ui-list-item".

On the other hand, Samsung does a very lousy job with it's SmartTV SDK. It's so bad that it looks like they don't even want people to develop apps for it.

According to the [API doc](http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_3/api_reference/appsframework_apis/ui_components_api/uiapi_list_sflist.html), you should indeed style class "sf-ui-list-item", but if you run your project with "Debug Samsung Smart TV App using Web Inspector" you can see that they use class "sf-ui-list-blured".

So, logical step would be to style:

```
#MenuList .sf-ui-list-blured { ... }
```

I would recommend that you maybe create your own styles and pass them as 3 parameters in ".sfList" command (classes: focusCssClass, blurCssClass and selectCssClass as stated in [API doc](http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_3/api_reference/appsframework_apis/ui_components_api/uiapi_list_sflist.html)).